# Make MORE / Hide Reveal Button @media Query / Browser Width Dependent

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, hide

I am currently using this code for a MORE hide/reveal button, but can't figure out how to make it be @media query dependent so it only shows up and works at particular browser width.

CSS:

```
<div>
    <p>
         Can I put a paragraph of text here?
         <div id="dots1">...</div>
    </p>
    <div style="display: none;" id="more1">
         <p>
            The text I want to be on read more
         </p>
    </div>
         <button class="btn" id="myBtn1">
            Read more
         </button>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    for (const btn of document.querySelectorAll('.btn')) {
      btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const [ dots, moreText ] = Array.from(btn.parentElement.querySelectorAll('div'));
        if (dots.style.display === "none") {
            dots.style.display = "inline";
            btn.innerHTML = "MORE";
            moreText.style.display = "none";
            } 
        else {
            dots.style.display = "none";
            btn.innerHTML = "LESS";
            moreText.style.display = "block";
            }
      });
    }
</script>
```

And that's essentially because it is dependent on this "span style" that has to be placed inline the HTML file. It won't work if I make that span style a class attribute.

```
<div style="display: none;" id="more1">
```

Either:

1. "display: none" needs to be rewritten in the JS so that it can be a class attribute, then I can put the class in a @media query
2. somewhere in the JS put in a line that says it starts happening at a particular @media query.

Separately, I would also like to get rid of the "dots" being part of the script. I currently just leave that  with the dots empty, but it's not perfect coding.

EDITED: I want to say that I want to have the text show up at a certain width without the more button, then be hidden by a button at another browser width. And also say "READ MORE" first and "READ LESS" or something different after it opens. Thank you very much!

Thank you!

Comment: You could just use a CSS media query to always show the text and hide the button if it isn't at the correct screen width. That way if it is the proper width, the button will be visible and the text will be hidden until the button is clicked.

Comment: I did try that, but then the text also doesn't show. I forgot to say that I want the text to show at a certain width, then be dependent on the button to show at another width. I'll amend the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, I hide the read more button and display the read more text by default. Then using a media query, I determine based on the size to hide the text and show the button. Then using javascript, I attach an event handler to the document and catch all of the btn-readmore clicks and toggle an active class that will display block or not.

```js
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  let el = e.target;
  if(el.className == "btn-readmore"){
     let moreTxt = el.parentNode.querySelector(".more-text");
     moreTxt.classList.toggle("active");
     el.innerHTML = (moreTxt.className.indexOf("active") > 0) ? "Read Less" : "Read More";
  }
});
```

```css
.active.more-text,.more-text{display:block;}
.btn-readmore{display:none}

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 1000px){
   .btn-readmore{display:block}
   .more-text{display:none;}
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
         Can I put a paragraph of text here?
    </p>
    <div class="more-text">
         <p>
            The text I want to be on read more
         </p>
    </div>
         <button class="btn-readmore">
            Read more
         </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. Is there a way to change the button to say something different when it opens up? Like say "READ MORE" first before clicking on it and then say "READ LESS" when it shows the hidden text, so people know to close it?

Comment: @IOio I have updated the javascript in my answer

Comment: LOVE! This is fantastic. Thank you so much. I'm just trying to design my own website and CSS is alright, but JS is a different animal :). You rock!

I honestly looked for a solution for months. Was using the workaround of copying all the text twice for different browser widths. Should have just asked this question long ago!